# Migrated questions don't show up in Stack Exchange stats

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, migration

I have a couple of questions on Stack Overflow that have been migrated to various other Stack Exchange sites. These are sites I didn't previously have an account for, but once I had a question migrated, I went ahead and made an account there. However, it has caused this behavior which is a bit odd:

[image]

The sites don't show that I have asked or answered any questions, but still show my rep.  I don't believe the answers get tallied in my Stack Overflow totals either. So it seems migrated questions don't get tallied anywhere on this page.

Comment: I guess it's one of those "it needs an action on the site to trigger the update" kind of issues.